# Given a transformation matrix, how do I find out what it does?

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm given the following matrix: $B =\begin{bmatrix} 1-2\sqrt{2} & 2-\sqrt{2} & 0 \\ 1-2\sqrt{2} & 2-\sqrt{2} & 0 \\ 1-\sqrt{2} &-1+\sqrt{2} & 1 \\\end{bmatrix}  $ and I'm supposed to find out whether it describes a rotation, a projection or a reflection.

I have so far found out that

- its determinant is $0$, so it has no inverse
- its set of fixed points is a plane described by the vector $(k, -k, j)$, where $k$ and $j$ are arbitrary real numbers
- its kernel is a line described by $n \cdot \left(2, 3-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, 1- \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \right)$, where $n \in \mathbb{R}$
- the dimension of its image (its rank) is $2$, since it only has two linearly independent rows
- the dimension of its kernel (its nullity) is $1$, since the kernel is a single line
- the last two points satisfy the rank-nullity-theorem:
  **rk** B + **nul** B = **dim** V, where the dimension is obviously $3$

I feel like that's quite a lot of information yet I do not know what kind of linear mapping the matrix performs.

---

I know so far that

- a rotation has

  - an orthogonal matrix where $AA^T = I^{3x3}$
  - also it has $det(A)=1 $

  neither of these is the case with our matrix $B$
- a projection satisfies $A=A^2$ , but that's also not the case
- a reflection satisfies $A^2 = I^{3x3}$ , well that's not the case either

I feel like it should be some kind of projection, since it maps a line (its kernel) to the coordinate origin $(0, 0, 0)$.

Answer (score 4):

It’s none of the above. You’ve already eliminated rotation and reflection by determining that the matrix is singular. A projection would satisfy $B^2=B$, so its only eigenvalues are $0$ and $1$, but $\operatorname{tr}B = 4-3\sqrt2$, so there’s at least one eigenvalue of $B$ that’s neither.

Answer (score 1):

You found the equation for the plane and you found the equation for the nullspace, a line. Observe that the dot product of your plane position vector and your nullspace line vector is zero. The nullspace vector is normal to the plane.

Because your transform, with zero determinant, is not invertible, you cannot have a reflection or rotation (both invertible operations) and by process of elimination you have a projection. Perhaps check the $A^2=A$ condition again?